# unexpected line drawed after creating svg wave

Tags: html, css, svg

[image]I'm using https://getwaves.io/ to create SVG waves but the problem is after creating this wave, an unexpected line will draw some times in different browsers

I want to know what's the problem and how I can fix it

Comment: Where is the line? Is it at the top or bottom of image, or is it on either sides? Maybe delete the Z in path is what you want.

Comment: it's at the bottom, I attached image to show

Comment: It will be because the bottom of the wave and the bottom of the background image don't line up properly.  But we can't diagnose the problem more accurately without some code.  Please update your question with a [MCVE].